# "Invalid object name" when referring to a table

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, jdbc, jtds

I am trying to connect to SQL server database from Android app. Connection works but I get expection because of Table

> java.sql.SQLException: Invalid object name 'dbo.Names'.

The SQL code I send to the server is

```
stmt.execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Names] ([name]) VALUES ('Test')");
```

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Here is the code:

```
static String serverIp = "xxx.database.windows.net:1433";
static String serverDb = "xxxApp";
static String serverUserName = "xxx";
static String serverPassword = "xxx";

Connection con;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    CheckLogin checkLogin = new CheckLogin();
    checkLogin.execute("");

}

public class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    String z = "";
    Boolean isSuccess = false;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String r) {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            con = connectionclass(serverUserName, serverPassword, serverDb, serverIp);

            if (con == null) {
                z = "Check Internet Access";
            } else {

                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                stmt.execute("INSERT INTO [dbo].[Names] ([name]) VALUES ('Test')");

                String x = ""; // DEBUG point
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            isSuccess = false;
            z = ex.getMessage();
        }

        return z;
    }


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection connectionclass(String user, String password, String database, String server) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection connection = null;
        String ConnectionURL = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver");
            ConnectionURL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://" + server + ";database=" + database + ";user=" + user + ";password=" + password + ";encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;";

            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnectionURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("error here 1 : ", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("error here 2 : ", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("error here 3 : ", e.getMessage());
        }
        return connection;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does that table exist in the database you're connected to?

Comment: @TZHX Yes it does

Comment: Have your app display the result returned by `stmt.getConnection().getCatalog()`. You may not be hitting the database you think you are.

Comment: @GordThompson getCatalog() returns 'master'...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SQL statement is failing because you are not using the correct connection URL format for jTDS so you are not actually connecting to the database specified by the String variable `serverDb`.

You are trying to use a connection URL parameter named `database` that jTDS does not recognize:

```java
String serverDb = "myDb";
String connUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:49242;database=" + serverDb;
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connUrl, myUid, myPwd)) {
    System.out.println(conn.getCatalog());  // prints: master
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```

Instead, you should be using the `server:port/database` format described in the [documentation](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html#urlFormat)

```java
String serverDb = "myDb";
String connUrl = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost:49242/" + serverDb;
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connUrl, myUid, myPwd)) {
    System.out.println(conn.getCatalog());  // prints: myDb
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace(System.err);
}
```